How to access options when extending a leaflet class?
I am trying to extend a Leaflet class, and looking at the documentation it gives this example:
var MyBoxClass = L.Class.extend({

    options: {
        width: 1,
        height: 1
    },

    initialize: function(name, options) {
        this.name = name;
        L.setOptions(this, options);
    }
    
});

var instance = new MyBoxClass('Red', {width: 10});

console.log(instance.name); // Outputs "Red"
console.log(instance.options.width); // Outputs "10"
console.log(instance.options.height); // Outputs "1", the default

However, if I try to access this.options.height in initialize after calling L.setOptions it is undefined. Instead there appears to be a this.options.prototype.height.
How should I be accessing options members so I get the default if the caller doesn't define a value?
Thanks

I may be misunderstanding your question but this.options.height in this example https://jsfiddle.net/hb6e5mo2/ seems to work just fine

I'm running my code in chrome and inside the initialize function after the call to  SetOptions my options member shows as undefined

Had trouble looking at the fiddle while mobile. Now looked at it and it's doing exactly what I expected (ie working), so it must be something about my version / environment. I'll try to replicate it in fiddle.

I figured it out, it turns out I had a bug that was explicitly setting the member I thought I couldn't access to undefined much earlier. Thank-you for your help
